# First ever bundle install, stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, stack, bundle, bundler

I have created a brand new rails project using the command
`rails new qbc --database=mysql`. It creates all the files perfectly fine, but
at the bundle install it errors out

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/usr/bin/bundle:23: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

[`gist.github.com/3956513`](http://gist.github.com/3956513)

I have searched and searched for the solution to this issue but I can't seem to
find anyone else who has experienced it. I am developing on Cygwin and I
wouldn't be surprised if that has something to do with it.

I tried creating a Gemfile with just the source and one gem in it in an empty
directory and bundle install still gives the same error. I have followed all of
the troubleshooting steps, reinstalled Cygwin and all packages, everything. What
keeps catching my eye is the `Fetching gem metadata` twice...is it possible that
bundler is caught in some kind of loop?

Comment: Check the current stack size with `ulimit -s` and try bumping it to 8192 if it's lower with `ulimit -s 8192`. I have not tried to develop in Cygwin, but my stack is certainly smaller there than the defaults I'm used to elsewhere.

Comment: @cjc343 - Unfortunately Cygwin doesn't allow you to change the stack size...in fact the only related option I've seen from searching around is that you can set the stack size for specific applications when you compile them yourself. Thing is, I know that bundler CAN work with the default Cygwin stack size because I have had it running perfectly fine in the past

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589341/ruby-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror. I get the same issue and haven't been able to resolve it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cygwin's pthread_attr_getstack reports about 90k by default. I think Cygwin is reporting the **committed** (used-so-far) stack size, not the **reserved** (total available) size. Then Ruby is treating that (i.e. 90k) as the maximum stack size ever.

To change the initial **committed** stack size:

```
peflags -X409600 `which ruby`
```

*Note the capitalized -X. Lowercase -x changes reserved stack size, not initially-committed stack space.*

This fixes all Ruby+Rails+Cygwin issues for me.

I don't know Ruby or Cygwin internals well enough to know which is the right fix, but it's probably one of these.

- Cygwin reports *reserved* stack size from pthread_attr_getstack.
- Ruby adds a build step to run the peflags command above.
- Ruby determines the available stack space a different way.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but here are the lines from the configure script: `cygwin*|mingw*)
                        : ${LDSHARED='$(CC) -shared $(if $(filter-out -g -g0,$(debugflags)),,-s)'}
                        XLDFLAGS="$XLDFLAGS -Wl,--stack,0x00200000,--enable-auto-import"
                        DLDFLAGS="${DLDFLAGS} -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import"
                        : ${LIBPATHENV=""}
                        rb_cv_dlopen=yes ;;`

Comment: thank you, i was getting strange intermittent SystemStackErrors running ruby under cygwin. this fixed it instantly.

Comment: This also helped me solve a deep stack issue when just running `rails server`.

Comment: Ruby-2.1.3 (rbenv) on Cygwin64 had been working fine for me for some time then out of the blue an `rspec` test started producing `SystemStackError`s. Little did I know it wasn't my specs fault. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think this answer is likely to be helpful, as it doesn't make any sense, but I solved it by:

```
$ gem install rake
$ gem install bundler

$ bundle install
```

It worked at that point without running into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows binaries encode the preferred stack size in the executable header. Cygwin binaries default to about 2M.

You can change this:

```
peflags -x8192000 `which ruby`
```

and re-run 'bundle install'. It's been working for me that way for some time now.

Comment: This didn't work. Even tried 18192000. I also found just getting the rails version will fail too: `$ peflags -x8192000 \`which ruby\`
/usr/bin/ruby: stack reserve size      : 8192000 (0x7d0000) bytes

Chloe@dumbopc /cygdrive/c/Sites/railsinstaller_demo
$ rails -v
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:118: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`